# Cmd.Parameters Vs Cmd.Parameters.Item

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am facing some awkward situation with VB.Net code.

I am having source code of ASP.Net using VB.Net which was written in late 2010.

It has been running fine until 3 days ago.

Below line of code was working till 3 days ago.

```
Cmd.Parameters("@idnum").Value = e.Item.Cells.Item(2).Text
```

But I did some changes in code and now above line of code was not working. I checked that System.SQL.Client reference is same and there is windows or .net framework update. I am not sure what happened.

Though I found the solution and here it is

```
Cmd.Parameters.Item("@idnum").Value = e.Item.Cells.Item(2).Text
```

But I am keen to learn what could be the possible reason of failure of later code.

EDIT 1: 
Here is the error if

> System.MissingMemberException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2146233070
>     Message=Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parameters' accepts this number of arguments.
>     Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
>     StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.OverloadResolution.ResolveOverloadedCall(String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure, Container BaseReference)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ResolveCall(Container BaseReference, String MethodName, MemberInfo[] Members, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, BindingFlags LookupFlags, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>          at HMGS.Order.grdItems_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) in C:\HMGS Dev Source BioUrja\WebSource\HMGS\HMIOnly\Orders\Order.aspx.vb:line 1937
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.OnItemDataBound(DataGridItemEventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.CreateItem(Int32 itemIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, ListItemType itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataGridColumn[] columns, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.DataBind()
>          at HMGS.Order.popItems(Object idnum) in C:\HMGS Dev Source BioUrja\WebSource\HMGS\HMIOnly\Orders\Order.aspx.vb:line 1885
>          at HMGS.Order.popInfo(Object idnum) in C:\HMGS Dev Source BioUrja\WebSource\HMGS\HMIOnly\Orders\Order.aspx.vb:line 841
>          at HMGS.Order.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\HMGS Dev Source BioUrja\WebSource\HMGS\HMIOnly\Orders\Order.aspx.vb:line 75
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     InnerException:

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved..

It was project setting **On Infer** property which was off when **On Infer** was set to ON issue resolved.

reference links 
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement)